# Creating a CDATA section using xsl:text element within xslt processor

Tags: orbeon

Assuming I have an XSL variable called $apps with XML content:

```
<APPLICATION><DATA1/><DATA2/><DATA3/></APPLICATION>
```

I am trying to generate a string from this XML, with XML special chars handled, using:

```
let $applicationsModified := <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$apps"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]></xsl:text>
```

What I get is:

```
let $applicationsModified := <?javax.xml.transform.disable-output-escaping?>&lt;/xsl:text&gt;&lt;xsl:copy-of select="$apps"/&gt;&lt;xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"&gt;<?javax.xml.transform.enable-output-escaping?>
```

What I want to get is:

```
<![CDATA[<APPLICATION><DATA1/><DATA2/><DATA3/></APPLICATION>]]>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You already asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815628/convert-copy-of-output-to-string-and-escape-xml-special-characters-like-less-tha/5822839#5822839 Please look at the answers and comments there.

Comment: That question was posted because CDATA section did not work for me - that question deals with serialization of XML.  Serialization is different from creating CDATA section.  Here I am specifically looking for a solution on how to produce a CDATA section as highlighted in the question.

Comment: Where is the output of your XSLT going? Into an XML pipeline? Asking because CDATA information is a funny beast: it is sometimes included, sometimes not. For example, the XML Infoset doesn't keep "The boundaries of CDATA marked sections".

Comment: It is submitted to XML DB using submissions processor and the results I have produced above are from the wire-capture of that submission (before it reaches the XML DB and after it has been submitted).

Comment: the `let $applicationsModified := ...` looks more like XQuery than XSLT. Also, when you say "what I get is…", how do you get that? Please edit your question to clarify it (we should have all the information needed from the question to reproduce the issue you're describing), or I will suggest to close it as being vague.